# Graphene-django - How to catch response of query?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, graphene-python

I use django and django graphene for make a graphql API.

In the view of my application, I use reactJS and [react-bootstrap-table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/). React-bootstrap-table expects that I pass it an object array but does not support [nested objects](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/444).

I created query in my **schema.py**:

```
class ApplicationNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        filter_fields = ['name', 'sonarQube_URL']
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

class Query(ObjectType):
    application = relay.Node.Field(ApplicationNode)
    all_applications = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ApplicationNode)
```

The answers to these queries are JSON nested objects like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allApplications": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QXBwbGljYXRpb25Ob2RlOjE=",
            "name": "foo",
            "sonarQubeUrl": "foo.com",
            "flow":{ 
                "id": "QYBwbGljYXRpb45Ob2RlOjE=",
                "name": "flow_foo"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QXBwbGljYXRpb25Ob2RlOjI=",
            "name": "bar",
            "sonarQubeUrl": "bar.com"
            "flow":{ 
                "id": "QXBwbGljYXRpb26Ob2RlOjA=",
                "name": "flow_bar"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have to put them flat before giving them to React-bootstrap-table.

What is the better way, intercept the results of graphene-django queries to put them flat or make this job in ReactJS view?

If the first way is better, how to intercept the results of graphene-django queries to put them flat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to wrap react-bootstrap-table in a new component. In the component massage the relay props into a flat structure as needed for react bootstrap table.

For example:

```
MyReactTable = ({allApplications}) => {
  let flatApplications = allApplications.edges.map(({node: app}) => {
    return {
      name: app.name,
      sonarQubeUrl: app.sonarQubeUrl,
      flowName: app.flow.name
    };
  });
  return (
    <BootstrapTable data={flatApplications} striped={true} hover={true}>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" dataSort={true}>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="sonarQubeUrl" dataSort={true}>Sonar Qube Url</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="flowName" dataFormat={priceFormatter}>Flow Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
  );
};
```